# Expo's Branch.subscribe() Not Triggering

Tags: react-native, expo, branch.io

I am unable to get Branch.subscribe to trigger when clicking on a deeplink generated from Branch.io. The deeplink opens the app (my-app), which is good, but any link with the same schema (my-app) would do that. So I cannot confirm that Expo's Branch is actually working on Android.

I tried a few variations. Starting with Expo's example:

```
componentDidMount() {
    logger('COMPONENT MOUNTED') // runs
    DangerZone.Branch.subscribe((bundle) => {
      logger('PLS WORK') // doesn't run
    });
  }
}
```

Branch's example:

```
  _unsubscribeFromBranch = null
  componentDidMount() {
    logger('COMPONENT MOUNTED') // runs
    _unsubscribeFromBranch = DangerZone.Branch.subscribe(({error, params}) => {
      logger('PLS WORK') // doesn't run
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (_unsubscribeFromBranch) {
      _unsubscribeFromBranch()
      _unsubscribeFromBranch = null
    }
  }
```

The logger inside the subscribe() call never triggers. The app opens on the deeplink url, the componentDidMount() runs, but subscribe does not react to the link.

I am using Expo's implementation of Branch (Expo v25, react-native-branch 2.0.0-beta.3). I want to avoid detaching from Expo if possible.

Additional error logged from the ADB:

```
04-04 11:41:42.319 30352 30352 E i       : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: abi25_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.branch.RNBranchModule
04-04 11:41:42.319 30352 30352 E i       : Runtime exception in RNObject when calling method initSession: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.reflect.Method[] java.lang.Class.getMethods()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Branch is not properly initialized. Can you confirm you have imported it with this statement?

```
import { DangerZone } from 'expo';
let { Branch } = DangerZone;
```

React-Native Branch is now on version 2.2.4. We have made many updates to the wrapper since the beta version. Can you upgrade to [2.2.4 manually](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking/releases/tag/v2.2.4)?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I omitted the imports for my example, but they have been imported from Expo's DangerZone. If I fail to import Branch, my app should have encountered an error because it's trying to use an undefined variable. We tried to manually update to the latest Branch, but it is also unresponsive. I don't know if Expo will work well with Branch if we do force the update though.

Comment: I'm confused why is DangerZone being used instead of the `react-native-branch` module, is this becasue Expo can't take manual modules and this is the workaround?

Comment: The module requires `react-native link react-native-branch`. I think modules that require `link` would require detaching. There are a few places where manually upgrading the version inside `package.json` without detaching works with little to no issue, but I was unable to do that here.